# How to use the asin() function in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, trigonometry

I am trying to use the asin() function in an iOS app to calculate an angle from the y axis. I am using trigonometry, but I must be doing something wrong with the asin() function, as when I try to pass in 0.707.... as asin(rotation) where rotation is a double equivalent to 0.707..., I get around 0.78....., where as my calculator gives me 44.991..., which is about correct from the variables passed in. What am I doing wrong, please can somebody help me?

Answer (score 8):

Your calculator is probably set to degrees.  Most computer libraries use radians.  You can convert using the formula `degrees = radians*180/pi`.

Comment: For the record, including <math.h> will give you a handy constant for π: M_PI

Comment: Thank you. I actually just figured it out before I checked this, but thank you anyway. What is the point of having radians?

Comment: In geometry, radians are the natural way to relate the length along an arc to its angle.  `s = rω`, where s = arc length, r = radius, and ω is angle in radians.  This leads naturally to the equation `C = 2πr`, the circumference is the arc length of an arc that sweeps out 2π radians.  In mathematics, `cos` and `sin` can be written as infinite series (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine#Series_definitions) if you take the argument `x` as radians.